# OGV works locally in Firefox, not served from S3 in video source as "video/ogg"

Tags: firefox, amazon-s3, mime-types, html5-video, ogg-theora

Okay, I'm pulling my hair out here.  My .ogv file plays back locally in Firefox, but not from amazon s3.  When I try to play it from the following video tag, I get the grey box with the lighter grey x in it.

```
<video id="12345" class="video-js" width="352" height="240" controls autoplay>
    <source src="working.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' />
    <source src="working.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
    <!-- Flash Fallback code omitted for clarity -->
  </video>
```

Here's what you need to know:

- Both HTML and video files are being served from a bucket on S3 in the same "directory."
- I have used S3 bucket explorer to change the MIME type to "video/ogg"
- The "working.ogv" file plays back beautifully in VLC and in Firefox 3.6.12 when played locally, so there shouldn't be an encoding issue.
- VLC *will* play the stream directly from S3 when I enter the URL.
- Chrome, Safari and Firefox all try to *download* the file when I enter the URL (none of them stream.)
- I have tried changing the source to the full URL for the video.
- I have tried omitting the "type" on the ogv source.
- I have tried various combinations of attributes inside the video tag.
- I have tried omitting the ogv source completely, and FF does not fall back to flash.
- Safari, Mobile Safari and Chrome all play the MP4 quite nicely.

Here's a link to a real-live example file:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/lifewayworship/videopreview/v/Silent_Night_90402_CL_A.ogv

Help!

Comment: Hmm.  So the file you link to is being sent as `video/ogv`.  Are you sure you set the type to `video/ogg` and not `video/ogv`?

Comment: Argh.  Thanks, @boris.  I had set MIME types to video/ogv instead of video/ogg.  I feel like deleting this post, but maybe it will help someone else who is pulling their hair out.  At least they can go down the checklist I provided!!! :D

Answer (score 3):

The MIME type you want is `video/ogg` not `video/ogv`; right now the server is sending the latter.

Answer (score 0):

Man, that sounds incredibly frustrating. Looks like you're doing all of the things I would recommend, and trying lots of variations/tests. I've got one idea, and two maybe not so good ideas:

1) I ran into encoding issues when I used Miro, and ended up having files that would play fine locally... but ended up behaving differently when I viewed them online. To ensure that it's not an encoding issue, try subbing in an existing .ogv file that you know works - possibly from some other site/tutorial.

Standby reference: [Big Buck Bunny](http://www.bigbuckbunny.org/index.php/download/)

2) This is a longshot, and it's me showing how little I know about these formats... but maybe try using .ogg as an extension, instead of .ogv? I looked and see that .ogv is meant for video, with .ogg being deprecated... but changing the file extension might reveal something about your encoding process.

3) Another longshot: kill the codecs attribute for your mp4 source.